# Oxyplot: Setting margin/padding for Oxyplot's heatmap

Tags: c#, margin, heatmap, oxyplot

I'm seeing space at the edges from my Oxyplot heat map widget. I would like to make X0,X1,Y0,Y1 be drawn at the very edge of the heat map paint canvas, i.e. no margins and padding. How is this done with OxyPlot's HeatMapSeries?

[image: Here's a screenshot]
I would like (0, 0) to be exactly at the lower left.

Answer (score 5):

Solved by setting the MinimumPadding and MaximumPadding to 0 on the LinearAxis. Default is 0.01%.